# undefined is not an object ('evaluating _this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native

I'm new programing with React Native and I got this issue with my code, I'm try to do a Splash screen and after that I want to make a Login that redirect me to another screen.

The Splash screen run well but when I'm in the Login Screen and I push the "Entrar" button, it crashes and shows the message.

`` ` ``

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Asset, SplashScreen } from 'expo';

import Splash from './screens/Splash';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import ForgotPass from './screens/ForgotPass';
import Home from './screens/Home';

App.js

export default class App extends React.Component
{
  componentWillMount()
  {
    this.setState({
      view: <Splash />
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        view: <Login />
      })
    }, 3000)
  }

  render()
  {
    return(
      this.state.view
    )
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Login.js

import React from 'react';
import { View, BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { Card, Button, FormLabel, Text, FormInput } from 'react-native-elements';
import { createStackNavigator, navigate } from 'react-navigation';

export default class Login extends React.Component
{
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Iniciar sesión',
    headerLeft: null,
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', function()
    {
      return true;
    });
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
        <Card>
          <FormLabel>Nombre de Usuario</FormLabel>
          <FormInput placeholder='NombreUsuario' />
          <FormLabel>Contraseña</FormLabel>
          <FormInput secureTextEntry placeholder='Contraseña' />

          <Button
            buttonStyle={{ marginTop: 20 }}
            backgroundColor='#03A9F4'
            title='Entrar'
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
          />
        </Card>
        <View style={{ paddingVertical: 20 }}>
          <Button
            title="¿Olvidó su contraseña?"
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ForgotPass')}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass navigation props in App.js file

```
componentWillMount()
{
  this.setState({
    view: <Splash />
  })

  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
      view: <Login navigation={this.props.navigation} />
    })
  }, 3000)
}
```

or you can use withNavigation in Login.js file

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';


export Default withNavigation(Login);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html this link will help you to learn more about withNavigation in react navigation