# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate') upon button click

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I am fairly new to react-native and react-navigation and trying to move from one screen to another via button click, keep getting this error. I've found similar questions here on SO ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53908935/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigation-navigate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064347/undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-this-props-navigation-navigate)) but they don't work for me, keep getting this error.

What I am doing is, I have an App.js that is the initial screen which for now shows a login form (called Splash):

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen';
import Splash from './Splash';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props; 

    return (
      <View>
        <Splash navigation={navigation}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen
  }
}, {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63'
    }
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

On my Splash screen I now have no functionality as I am just trying to get it to move to my HomeScreen when I hit the Login button:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    ScrollView,
    Text,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

class Splash extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);                
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{padding: 20}}>
                <TextInput  autoCapitalize="none" 
                            onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()} 
                            autoCorrect={false} 
                            keyboardType='email-address' 
                            returnKeyType="next" 
                            placeholder='Email address' 
                            placeholderTextColor='rgba(225,225,225,0.7)'/>

                <TextInput  returnKeyType="go" 
                            ref={(input)=> this.passwordInput = input} 
                            placeholder='Password' 
                            placeholderTextColor='rgba(225,225,225,0.7)' 
                            secureTextEntry/>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
                            <Text>LOGIN</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>     
            </ScrollView>
            )
    }
};

export default Splash;
```

What happens now is that as soon as I hit the login button, I get the error in the title. Any clues on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is Home or Splash your initial screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove App component, you don't need it in this case. Make Splash as your initial screen

```
const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Splash: {
    screen: Splash
  },
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileScreen
  }
}, {
    initialRouteName: "Splash",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: '#e91e63'
    }
});
```

then export AppContainer directly

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
export default AppContainer
```